# I have a problem with the yandex translate api

Tags: javascript, python, yandex-api

I have two query code examples that return the same error related to the API key, but it is correct.

Example of error:

> code: 16,
> message: 'The token is invalid',

Js

```
const IAM_TOKEN = 'IAM_TOKEN';
const folder_id = 'folder_id';
const target_language = 'ru';
const texts = ["Hello", "World"];

const body = {
    targetLanguageCode: target_language,
    texts: texts,
    folderId: folder_id,
};

const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${IAM_TOKEN}`,
};

fetch('https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Ошибка при выполнении запроса:', error);
    });
```

Python

```
import requests

IAM_TOKEN = 'IAM_TOKEN'
folder_id = 'folder_id'
target_language = 'ru'
texts = ["Hello", "World"]

body = {
    "targetLanguageCode": target_language,
    "texts": texts,
    "folderId": folder_id,
}

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer {0}".format(IAM_TOKEN)
}

response = requests.post('https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate',
    json = body,
    headers = headers
)

print(response.text)
```

Tried different XMLHttpRequest, fetch, axios queries